# Como bloquear printscreen em uma página web?

Tags: javascript, html, navegador-de-internet

Sei que para desenvolvimento Android existe o comando:

```
getwindow().setflags(windowmanager.layoutparams.flag_secure windowmanager.layoutparams.flag_secure)
```

Que impede o *printscreen* e até a gravação da tela por algum app. Queria saber se tem como implementar algo parecido em um site web por alguma modificação on DOM ou algo do tipo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não tem como.

O HTML, CSS e JavaScript de qualquer website são executados em um tipo de *sandbox* que o navegador cria para cada "aba". Se o próprio navegador, como aplicação, já impede que o JavaScript, por exemplo, execute ações que ultrapassem escopo da aba a qual o *script* está sendo executada, manipulações que envolvam o sistema operacional estão *muito* acima da "alçada de permissões" do JavaScript executado pelos sites.

Em outras palavras, o nível de restrição é muito maior do que o JavaScript pode executar. A captura de tela não é um recurso de aplicações (como o navegador), mas sim do sistema operacional.

O *comando* que você mencionou é uma API fornecida pelo *sistema operacional* Android para que *aplicações* manipulem a captura de tela. O navegador, como aplicação, poderia acessar essa API, mas o JavaScript, que roda *dentro* do navegador não tem "permissão" para acessá-la.

Seria uma baita falha de segurança permitir que o JavaScript acessasse esse tipo de API relativamente mais *low-level* do sistema operacional.

Se estiver falando de Node.js ou Deno, aí é outra história (mas não é o caso).

Answer (score -1):

Olá. Bem isso não é possível usando javascript puro. Acontece que para impedir a captura de tela vc precisa de um sistema chamado DRM(digital right menenger). Tem o Google widevine (que é o único gratuito), Microsoft PlayReady, Apple FairPlay. Para usar o widevine é preciso ir no site deles, a utilização é gratuita porém precisa de uma licença que vc ganha entrando em contato, aí vc tem acesso para usar o sistema. É grátis porém é preciso cadastrar, então você aplica ele na página, os DRM em geral eles funcionam usando um sistema que faz uma criptografia da página ou vídeo ou o que quiser, e ele dá uma chave para o reprodutor de vídeo ou o modo de exibição da página(ou para o que vc quiser) então esses que tem o acesso a chave pode descriptografar e exibir o conteúdo da página. Se o sistema de captura de tela(seja vídeo ou print screen) for tentar ver o conteúdo ele não tem a chave assim não pode descriptografar, daí vem aquela tela preta. Esse sistema criptografa em tempo real a página.

O Widevine funciona em todos os sistemas google e navegadores porém sem muitas garantias nos navegadores Safari e Edge(mas funcina pela criptografia) e não funciona no Xbox. O PlayReady já garante proteção nos sistemas Microsoft incluindo Xbox e Edge. E o Apple garante um melhor funcionamento no Safari.

Porém no geral funciona nos navegadores por causa da criptografia e gerenciamento de chaves. Porém o de cada empresa garante segurança extra em seus sistemas.

Answer (score -3):

Olá, também me encontrei nessa situação, precisava fazer um site que
impedisse isso. Bem até agora eu ainda estou desenvolvendo a solução, más eu tenho essa opção

`function alerta(){
alert('A página não pode ser salva.');

}
function verificaBotao(oEvent){
var oEvent = oEvent ? oEvent : window.event;
var tecla = (oEvent.keyCode) ? oEvent.keyCode : oEvent.which;
if(tecla == 91|| tecla == 16 || tecla == 91){
alerta()
blocks()

}
}

document.onkeypress = verificaBotao;
document.onkeydown = verificaBotao;
document.oncontextmenu = alerta;`

Porém não é de autoria minha, então aqui as fontes: http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3652/como-bloquear-o-botao-ctrl-e-impedir-impressao-de-pagina-com-javascript.aspx

Quando eu achar a solução final eu mando. EU quero fazer como a netflix e Disney+ que ao fazer o print ele aparece uma tela escura enquanto durar o processo de print, após isso ele some. OBG

Comment: A pergunta não é sobre salvar o texto ou source da página, nem imprimir. É sobre "printscreen" (que apesar do nome "print", atualmente significa "fotografar" ou "capturar" a imagem da tela, ou de um pedaço dela).